# proof of number of prime factors of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given an integer $n$ between 1 and 1000000, how do you directly prove that $n$ has at most 19 prime factors (with multiplicity)?

I'm quite stuck on how to do this. I can understand the base case which is $n=2$. This obviously is correct, but I don't know how to continue with this proof from here on out.

Any help is great.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to prove this by induction. Don't. Instead ask yourself what's the smallest possible product of six primes? (Not necessarily distinct, the six primes could all be the same...)

Comment: Ok, if you're going to change 300 to 1000000 then I change 6 to 20.

Comment: Hint: Any number with $20$ prime factors is at least $2^{20}>1000000$.

Comment: If we are counting multiplicity then all $2$'s is the worst case.

Comment: 2^6 is the smallest product of 6 primes. I get what you're trying to say, but how do I lay out my proof?

Comment: Sorry for the edit, I realised 300 and 5 were wrong lol. And I have since read the comments and I seemed to have missed something really obvious :P Thank you

Comment: Is there any way to prove this directly?

Comment: Let $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$. Then $n\ge 2^{a_1+\cdots+a_k}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Since I have done research in logic, I don't know what a direct proof is. But maybe you would consider an induction proof direct. Can be done, more awkward than the natural proof.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something along the lines of an induction proof. What would be the inductive step? I'm really not quite sure how to approach it

Answer (score 3):

Assume that there exists an integer $n\le 1000000$ with $20$ prime factors. Then each of these prime factors is at least $2$, so $n$ is at least the product of twenty $2$s, that is, $2^{20}=1048576>1000000$; this contradicts our hypothesis and therefore there is no such integer.

Comment: I thought proof by contradiction is not a direct proof?

Comment: I understand this, but how do you prove this directly?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this. We can prove it constructively by the same method: all numbers with $20$ prime factors are at least $2^{20}>1000000$, so all numbers which are less than or equal to $1000000$ must have at most $19$ prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

$2$ is the smallest prime number. So the smallest possible number with 20 prime factors is $2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2......\cdot 2\cdot 2$ which is $2^{20}$ which is more than your number

Comment: how do you prove this inductively?